# JavaScript mouseover/changing pics from one to ten

Tags: javascript

My counter goes after 10 times to 0.
Remember I need it to 1 not 11 or 0!
I need every time a new jpg, for example test.1.jpg, test.2.jpg,test.3.jpg and so on.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            
                var timer, counter = 1,
                    changepic = function(pic) {
            
                        var src = pic.attr("src");
            
                        counter = counter + 1;
            
                        if (counter == 11) { // <- i tested my if clauses but not working any ideas?maybe we can solve it with easy if clauses
                            counter = 1;
                        }
            
                        pic.attr("src", src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('.') - 1) + counter + ".jpg");
            
                    };
                
                $('img').hover(function() {
            
                    var $this = $(this);
            
                    timer = setInterval(function() {
                        changepic($this);
                    }, 1000);
            
                }, function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                });
            
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="float:left;">
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="pics/test.1.jpg" /><br />Text</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes when counter equals 11;

```
src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('.') - 1) + counter + ".jpg"; 
//test.1 + 1 + .jpg ---> test.11.jpg
```

try

```
src.replace(/\d{1,2}\.jpg$/, counter + ".jpg");
```